# Apache permission error on WAMP

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I may be missing the obvious posting, but everything I've seen seems to apply to an older version of Apache with a different httpd.conf file.

I have the good old "You don't have permission to access / on this server" message.

With an older version of Apache that I used to use, the "order deny,allow"  followed by "allow from all" worked. Not with this new one.

Here's what I think the applicable section is that I need to change. I haven't seen this exact wording in other posts:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it...

1. Change httpd.conf to have "require all granted"
2. Change httpd-vhosts line "Require local" to "Require all granted"

It was the second file that I needed to change. (and no others, at least for me)